# Why can't I find kernel headers on CentOS 7 when trying to install VirtualBox Guest Additions?

Tags: centos, kernel, virtualbox

I have a minimal CentOS 7 installation as a VirtualBox 5.0.16 r105871 guest on a Windows 8.1 host.  `uname -r` reports "3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64".

When I try to run `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` I get an error that "The headers for the current running kernel were not found" and suggesting I do `yum install kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64`.  Yet `yum list kernel-devel` shows that is already installed (as is `kernel-headers` and the appropriate version).

Adding some logging to `vboxadd`, I find that it is looking for headers in `/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64/build` which turns out to be a dead link to a missing `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64`.  Indeed, `/usr/src/kernels/` is empty.

Googling around suggests that many versions of CentOS require patches to VBGA for the installation to work but I don't see any such notes specific to CentOS 7 or that refer to missing kernel headers.

Comment: Chris, please mark the answer to this query.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem using this:

```
yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```

Comment: The kernel-devel and kernel versions installed may not match exactly, and this command install the right version

Comment: This is the best command to install Linux headers. I used it to install VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Answer (score 3):

Prompted by https://serverfault.com/questions/613256/trying-to-remove-packages-with-yum-however-it-is-failing I did some clean up then `yum list` no longer showed `kenel-devel` so I installed it and `/usr/src/kernels/` is no longer empty and installing the Guest Additions succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 8 install

```
yum install -y gcc perl kernel-headers kernel-devel elfutils-libelf-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Mount VirtualBox Guest Additions drive: From device menu click on Install VirtualBox guest additions option and type the following command

```
yum install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Copy the `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` file from the drive to the root directory using following command:

```
cp /media/cd-rom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run /root/
```

Make it executable and install it:

```
chmod 755 /root/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
cd /root/Desktop
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

By the way, now for CentOS 7, `open-vm-tools` is recommended officially.

> $ ./vmware-install.pl
>
> open-vm-tools packages are available from the OS vendor and VMware recommends using open-vm-tools packages. See http://kb.vmwaare.com/kb/2073803 for mroe information.
>
> Do you still want to proceed with this installation? [yes]

Comment: 1. you have a typo in your link and 2. is this relevant for VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

I found just doing the following command resolved the issue with the standard install method.

Verify the headers are missing:

```
uname -r

# Verify the kernel version doesn't appear in the following location

ls /usr/src/kernels*
```

Overachieve the install:

```
yum install -y gcc perl kernel-headers kernel-devel
```

Verify the headers are now installed

```
ls /usr/src/kernels*
```

Reload the guest additions cd for it to auto-prompt install or cd into the disk drive and excute autorun.sh with root privileges.